# Passing variable into @Styles.Render function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

With razor, rendering a specific bundle of stylesheets is done with:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

This refers to the `BundleConfig` file which has the line:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
```

... pointing to the `site.css` file, inside the `Content` folder.

I wanted to set a variable (I've tried a session variable) like this:

```
Session["cssTheme"] = "~/Content/css";
```

So I could put it in the `Styles.Render` function, something like this:

```
@Styles.Render(@Session["cssTheme"])
```

But it gets an error of invalid arguments.

I wanted to do this so I could change the session variable value (to another style bundle) and that way change the css style of my web application.

So, how can I pass an edited variable into the `Styles.Render` function?

Comment: which is teh exact error, and where do you set the session variable? The problem can be a nullvalue passed to `Render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `Session` is dynamic, meaning it can hold any type inside. When you just pull out a value, it's technically of type `object`. `Styles.Render` expects a parameter of type `string`, so you need to cast the value to a `string` first:

```
@Styles.Render(@Session["cssTheme"] as String)
```

Then, there's the problem that you could potentially receive a null value if either that session variable is not set at all, or has been set to something other than a string value that can't be converted to a string. So, to compensate for that, you should provide some fallback for nulls:

```
@Styles.Render(@Session["cssTheme"] as String ?? "~/Content/css")
```

Now, it will either use whatever is in the session variable, or "~/Content/css" as a last resort. Bear in mind though, that this is still pretty brittle. If `Session["cssTheme"]` is set to a string, but not a properly formatted bundle reference, you'll still get an error, and a runtime error at that, which is ugly. Ideally, you should have some sort of value sanitization routine that you run `Session["cssTheme"]` through first before passing it to `Styles.Render`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, casting as a string worked. I'm a bittle puzzled though because the `@` before session isn't highlighted like the one before Styles (in the code editor, that is). This suggests that it is not being recognized despite the fact that it actually is

Comment: That's actually pretty common. The syntax highlighting in Razor views often jacks up. Try closing the tab and editing the file again. That will usually wake it up.

Comment: It didn't wake it up, it remains as a common char

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your model is MyModel and it has string property StyleSheet
so you have your view like

```
@model MyModel

@Styles.Render(model.StyleSheet)
```

Additionally you can get set this property from Session like below

```
public StyleSheet {
get {
    if(Session["cssTheme"]!=null)
     return Session["cssTheme"] as String 
     else 
       return   "defaultTheme";
}
set 
{
Session["cssTheme"]=value;
}
}
```