# Are you allowed to create seperate ASP bundles for resources in the same directory?

Tags: css, asp.net, bundle

Suppose I have a directory with multiple css files. Is there a way to create and reference multiple ASP bundles for the same directory?

Let's say you have a folder with several stylesheets.

I know you can include specific files by their virtual paths like this:

```
//Bundle1
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css"));
```

What if I add another bundle, and this one includes stylesheets that are in the same directory as the previous bundle?

```
//Bundle2
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

Now that I've created the bundles, I want to reference them.

I know I can call the following if there was just one bundle for the directory

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
```

The problem I'm having with `Styles.Render` though is that it only accepts a virtual path to a path. Lets say you create more than one bundle in the same directory (if that is even possible). You can't use `Styles.Render` to select which bundle you want. You can only give it a path. Is there another way to reference a bundle you create in BundleConfig without `Styles.Render`?

Or is `Styles.Render` is the only way to reference any style bundle in the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are you allowed to create seperate ASP bundles for resources in the
>   same directory?

Yes

---

> How would I reference these bundles with the Styles.Render method?

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/CssBundle1")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/CssBundle2")
```

The important thing to illustrate here is the reasoning behind bundling and the intended use of it. Bundling exists to reduce the number of requests and improve the load time of your application. You could do this manually, but you would have spaghetti code to manage. The bundling is there to keep everything modularized and easily organized.

---

## Where I think there might be confusion

`StyleBundle("~/Content/magicaunicornsdacningonrainbowsthisnameisrelative")`

When you create a bundle, the virtual path can be named whatever you want. You bundle it in categories that makes sense.

```
//Bundle1
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/pets").Include(
          "~/Content/dog",
          "~/Content/cat",

//Bundle2
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cities").Include(
          "~/Content/memphis.css",
          "~/Content/bejing.css",

//Bundle3
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/people").Include(
          "~/Content/joseph.css",
          "~/Content/michael.css",
```

With the bundles created, you make sure to call the bundles in the order you need them, loading only what is needed for each page.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/pets", "~/Content/cities")
* LOTS OF STUFF LOADED HERE! BUT YOU DO NOT NEED THE PEOPLE BUNDLE RIGHT AWAY *
@Styles.Render("~/Content/people")
```

You would simply create a different bundle for that references all the needed files, and you would call that bundle as needed. If you need to break up the order in which a file renders scripts or styles then you have multiple bundles. MVC is a lot about proper modularization, so you're always working up towards a root or singularity.

---

## Getting more advanced

Obviously you can kick it up a notch. The next steps include using .less or .sass preprocessors for your style bundles. Those will help with very detailed modularization. Next, you can start using variables and conditions to determine which bundles should be run, linked below.

> Or is Styles.Render is the only way to reference any style bundle in
>   the HTML?

There are other ways to reference css files via code. For instance, **you could write a simple `for loop`** to accomplish the task of writing the needed css scripts. Additionally, **you could use razor variables.**

---

## Resource

[Variables in Styles.Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457173/passing-variable-into-styles-render-function)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Wow thanks, this is exactly what i needed, and yes you're right about where I was confused! I thought an exact path to the resources was necessary, but you can name it whatever you want.